# Login EventListener not firing on production side

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, event-listener

I have an event listener that should fire when a user logs in in my Symfony setup.

I have the following in my services.yml

```
...
d_user.login_listener:
    class: D\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
    arguments: []
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber', event: 'security.interactive_login' }
```

and in my login listener I simply have this:

```
<?php

namespace D\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        echo 'user logged in';
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            'security.interactive_login' => array(array('onSecurityInteractiveLogin', 18))
        );
    }
}
```

On my dev server I correctly see the text "user logged in" before redirection, but on my production server it just logs in without the event firing. I'm modifying this later to set a session var on user login. I just need to get the method called.

Any advice? I've tried clearing the cache for prod and dev on my production environment, but that didn't help.

Comment: are you logging in via "remember me" ? keep in mind that your listener only triggers on interactive login , not on login via "remember me".

Comment: I was actually having issues with the value not returning the same from the database because I had forgot to update related form classes. My issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging with echo is discouraged. If you want an output, use the logger!

```
namespace D\UserBundle\EventListener;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $logger;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info('user logged in');
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            'security.interactive_login' => array(array('onSecurityInteractiveLogin', 18))
        );
    }
}
```

and inject the logger in your service defintion, preferrable with a nice channel name:

```
d_user.login_listener:
    class: D\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
    arguments: [@logger]
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber', event: 'security.interactive_login' }
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: d_user }
```

Comment: Easy and quick debugging looks different to me :) ... [ladybug](https://github.com/raulfraile/ladybug) offers nice dump output ... or (best option) [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) integrated with your IDE would be my choices, [FirePHP](http://firephp.org/) together with the browser plugin can be quite useful for quick debugging aswell.

Comment: He want a output. Xdebug works ok, firephp/chromephp depends on monolog and logged messages and is enabled only in dev mode per default and should not be enabled in prod.

Comment: And with ladybug, it's like var_dump an echo. Not sure if you get the output into the buffer. But debugging techniques are different :) I like to use the logger, 'cause i use it in most services.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Pazi. I was able to solve my problem now. I determined that production worked correctly, and found that my database values were just in mismatch :)

Comment: @Pazi i actually use xdebug all the time - as it works flawlessly without having to turn classes into services just for debugging. ladybug does work like var_dump but dumps objects nicely and even provides links to the corresponding api documentation. Further FirePHP can be used without any service integration and does not depend on monolog, there is a firephp handler for monolog though but you can use firephp without monolog :)

Comment: @nifr to all yes, indeed. But in context of symfony it feels weird to use FirePHP directly instead of monolog ^-^