# How to pass symfony2 login/pass credentials to strophe.js with openfire server?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have simple login/register app written in symfony2. I am using db encoder for checking user/password combination. And that part is working great.

I have a problem during login. I do not understand login_check path?
Where is controller for that?

I need to catch plain password during user login so I can pass that username and plain password to php xmpp namespace which will check user/pass at openfire server.

Please tell me if I have wrong approach for this.
I really need some guidance.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by adding an event listener that fires on user login.

services.yml

```
services:
    d_user.login_listener:
      class: Chat\IndexBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
      arguments: []
      tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber', event: 'security.interactive_login' }
```

and listener

```
namespace Chat\IndexBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        die(var_dump($event->getRequest()));

    }
    //...etc

}
```

in that `die(var_dump($event->getRequest()));` now I can catch user and pass and pass it to openfire server from which i can get sid, rid and jid and attach to that session on frontend.

[this answer was very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827681/login-eventlistener-not-firing-on-production-side).

Answer (score 1):

Please see [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406446/how-does-the-login-check-path-route-work-without-default-controller-action/17406584#17406584) to a similar question for a quick introduction to the special "*route*" `form_login.check_path`

Comment: I am using default user_db, entity User, as for your manual, do you mean that I  have to switch to new provider service in order to access data that I need username/plain password?

Comment: what do you mean by default user_db ?

Comment: my security provder is providers:
         user_db:
             entity: { class: Chat\IndexBundle\Entity\User, property: username}

Comment: is there any way that i can to some sort of pre-auth action first?

Comment: thank you for your help, but i used event listener that fires on user login. i added answer.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out yourself. You might consider showing some appreciation by at least upvoting my answer. it clearly provides the answer for the `I have a problem during login. I do not understand login_check path? Where is controller for that?` part of your question and probably hinted you into the right direction towards your solution. happy coding :)